# jdm. passen vs zu jdm. passen

Tags: difference

I have encountered these two forms of the verb "passen". Is there a difference between them?
What's their difference in the context of this example:

> Dieses Hemd passt mir.
>
> Dieses Hemd passt zu mir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context "Das Hemd passt mir" means "it fits" in the sense that it is fitting nicely and isn't too wide or too small. "Das Hemd passt zu mir" goes a bit beyond that. It means that clothing "fits your personality" or the imagery on it expresses your viewpoints.

Answer (score 1):

> Dieses Hemd passt mir.

this shirt fits (it is the right size).

> Dieses Hemd passt zu mir.

could be thought of as putting you and the shirt in one conceived category. So even if the size doesn't fit, it could suit you for other reasons. (Maybe you are known for your outgoing personality and the shirt is very colorful or something similar).